# Console prints to display signal level in c

Tags: mobile, signals, indicator

How to create a mobile signal indicator and horizontal volume control in headless c program?

I know how to create a progress bar ...etc. But in Linux do we have any library support graphic creation like graphic.h in windows

Answer (score 0):

i have found solution to move the cursor to desired places with escape sequence. With that i can create mobile signal indicator like below.

code for the same:

```
void draw_antenna(int level)
{
        static current_level = 0;
        unsigned char cnt = 0, l = 0;
        //let assume atenna having 5 level (0-5) and 5 is max
        // 5x5 matrix and color need to be controled in column
        for (cnt = 0; cnt <= ANTENNA_L; cnt++)
        {
                for (l = 0; l < cnt; l++)
                {
                        if (cnt <= level)
                                printf("\033[%d;%dH\033[0;42m\033[1;32m%c\033[0m", 15-l, 25+(cnt*2),' ');
                        else
                                printf("\033[%d;%dH\033[48;5;7m\033[1;34m%c\033[0m", 15-l, 25+(cnt*2),' ');
                        fflush(stdout);
                }
        }
        printf("\033[%d;%dH \033[1;33m%.*so\033[1;30m%*s\033[0m", 16, 25, level*2, TT,10-(level*2),"");
        //update current status
        current_level = level;
}
```

*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NolA.jpg)

Comment: i have not included entire program. But i hope this will serve the required. pls forgive for the  pic  quality(took via mobile).